# How to calculate packet loss rate with scapy?

Tags: networking, tcp, scapy, packet-sniffers, packet-loss

I'm trying to calculate packet loss rate from youtube when a video is running.

I sniff packets one by one by Scapy, on **eth0** and filter **TCP** packets with **IP** header.

To calculate packet loss rate, I should have a number of **received packets** and a number of **sent packets** (or excepted packets).

I can easily calculate the number of received packets, but I have a problem with sent packets from youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more google search I found an article from the Cisco that explained how to approximate packet loss rate base on the bandwidth.

This is the link, that helps me I hope that can help you too.

[Bandwidth, Packets Per Second, and Other Network Performance Metrics](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/security-center/network-performance-metrics.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try this:

Prepare simulated traffic with low, medium and high traffic. Since you will generate traffic you will know in advance total packets that will be sent.

1. First Capture all the traffic with tcpdump.
2. Second Capture all the traffic with scapy (avoid saving packets to disk with python).

You will see the following:

- Low traffic **25% packet** loss with scapy.
- Medium traffic **67% packet** loss with scapy.
- High traffic **89%! packet** loss with scapy.

Source of data: Computer Security – ESORICS 2011: 16th European Symposium on Research computer security.

I tried my self and I got the same results.
Without libpcap enabled scapy packet loss was 96%.

Remember tcpdump is almost the perfect case to compare to.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your accurate answer, but I try another way.
Because I hadn't accessed to packet that they sent from source so I Should approximate the packet loss rate.

Then after more google search, I found an article from Cisco which helped me. 

This is the link to this article:
[link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/security-center/network-performance-metrics.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit more complicated than that, you need to look at retransmissions (packets not acknowledged within their timeout limit).

You cannot see packets from the other side that were lost before they reached you. What you could do is look at the TCP sequence number and see if there are any gaps where you receive packets out of order.

This could be an indication of packet loss but is no guarantee. You may have to do some experimenting with the time limit of how much gap between two packets to allow before counting it as a retransmission and not just out of order arrival for other reasons.

I recommend reading as much as you can about the TCP protocol to understand the details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: But for this Project, I need reliable data.